# Prevent clients from getting the same record from API

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a very simple .NET core API that serves clients tasks. When a client requests a task, API updates it's status and returns the task to client. However i have noticed that if multiple clients request a task at the same time, they end up getting the same task. Here's relevant controller code:

```
        [HttpPost("next",Name = "RequestJob")]
        public ActionResult<QueJobReadDto> RequestJob(Robot robot)
        {
            var job = _repository.RequestJob();
            var registeredJob = _repository.RegisterJob(robot.RobotName, job);
            _repository.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<QueJobReadDto>(registeredJob));
        }
```

As you can see there are two methods used, "RequestJob" and "RegisterJob". RequestJob finds a record with a status of "In Que" and RegisterJob updates the status of the record to "In Progress". Here are the relevant implementations:

```
        public QueJob RequestJob()
        {
            
            return _context.QueJobs
                .Where(queJob => queJob.Status == "In Que")
                .OrderBy(queJob => queJob.JobGuid)
                .ToList()
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

```
        public QueJob RegisterJob(string worker, QueJob qj)
        {
            qj.Status = "In Progress";
            qj.Start = DateTime.UtcNow;
            qj.Worker = worker;
            qj.JobGuid = qj.JobGuid;
            _context.Update(qj);
            return _context.QueJobs.Find(qj.JobGuid);
        }
```

My question is: how can i couple these methods so the clients will never get the same task?

Comment: This is a concurrency issue, and some reading is required in order to solve this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: That is because if multiple threads call on `RequestJob` both of them will get the same data as it is a simple read operation. You can avoid that by using locking either on the code level or on the database side. You can enclose call to `RequestJob` (critical section of the code) within a `lock` block (which is equivalent to a `Monitor`) or use mechanisms that obtain locks on the row of the database. Though the first approach is simpler to implement, consider things like performance before taking a decision

Comment: Thank you both, i'm doing the reading now.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri: The lock-approach you suggest, is kind of inapproriate in a controller in my opinion. This will affect all requests, and may degrade performance to a critical level. Only request that are trying to modify a record in change, should be blocked.

Comment: @RoarS. - You rightly pointed out that the performance is going to be impacted in this scenario (I pointed out performance considerations in my comment for the same reason). However, in (only) this scenario, I see that there is not going to be any difference as all the incoming requests are going to go through this concurrency bottleneck (be it on the code side or on the EF side). I believe the best approach will be to update the status of the top most row at the time of fetch itself with a pessimistic locking strategy. Would be willing to stand corrected on this if otherwise :)

Comment: I should also mention that when I encounter problems like this, it is always because of some flaw in system design. Main problem in this case, is that a multi-threaded environment is prosessing a queue. RequestJob does more that the name promises; it also register a job. By splitting this into two calls; RegisterRequest and  RequestJobStatus would be a start. Then a singleton service could process the queue one-by-one. There will still be an issue that multiple calls file requests for the same job, but with a singleton queue processor, this can be handled by setting a denied status on request

Comment: So far, what i have understood is either i will have to implement pessimistic locking (which EF doesn't provide) or will have to do multiple calls from the client side (in the case of a conflict) with a singleton queue service.

Comment: The economy version would be to use suggestion from @SaiGummaluri. It won't be pretty, but it will do the job. Question is if a bottleneck arises.

Comment: @RoarS. - I do not see a way with the current design that eliminates the concurrency bottleneck. The scenario could be dealt more like a state machine in this case and having a transition state between 'InQueue' and 'InProgress'. This is sort of an overhaul of the existing structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try out the economy version, add this to the top of your controller

```
private const int LockTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100;
private static readonly object LockObject = new object();
```

Then

```
[HttpPost("next",Name = "RequestJob")]
public ActionResult<QueJobReadDto> RequestJob(Robot robot)
{
  if (!Monitor.TryEnter(LockObject, LockTimeoutInMilliseconds))
  {
     // return an approriate error messsage
  }

  try
  {
    var job = _repository.RequestJob();
    var registeredJob = _repository.RegisterJob(robot.RobotName, job);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<QueJobReadDto>(registeredJob));
  }
  finally
  {
    Monitor.Exit(LockObject); // ensure that the lock is released.
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tested this out and it works, thank you and @SaiGummaluri.